# Everyone singular or plural in "except" questions

Tags: grammatical-number

1)Everyone, *except* Jess and Susie, **was** present at the company meeting yesterday.

2)Everyone, *except* Jess and Susie, **were** present at the company meeting yesterday.

Which is correct?

Comment: Remove the parenthesis and the delimiting commas (you could have alternatively used brackets, dashes, or even zero punctuation here) and ask what you would use then.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is the correct sentence. The subject of the verb 'to be' (conjugated as 'was' in the correct sentence) is the collective pronoun 'everyone', which, as a collection, is a singular entity.

The clause in parenthesis ('*except* Jess and Susie') does modify what constitutes that singular entity, but it is ancillary to the main clause. Even if the group ('everyone') is smaller in the absence of Jess and Susie, neither of whom are subjects to the verb in the main clause, the group itself remains a discrete, singular entity.

A group is still **a** group, even when **it** is missing some members.

Comment: Even when they modify a plural noun, the quantifiers _each_ and _every_ are singular, and govern singular verb agreement: _Each (one) of the boys **is** prepared; Every one of the boys **is** prepared._ On the other hand, _all_ is always plural, and can't modify a singular count noun: _All (of) the boys **are** prepared._ It's a random assignment, like allowing either singular or plural with _none_: _None of the boys is/are prepared_.